# Is there a way to update the graph/paper or all modified elements in the graph in JointJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jointjs, rappid

Basically I'm receiving Cell attributes from a file and I want to replace the corresponding Cells in the graph with the updated attributes but I can't seem to refresh the graph after I've applied the new attributes.

Based on the [JointJS docs](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v0.9/joint.html), it seems like graph.resetCells is what I'm looking for but it doesn't actually do anything when I try it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
paper.render()
```

paper is the view and graph is the model

Comment: That seems to just turn all the elements invisible and unselectable

Comment: do you have a sample high level code. And also how are you applying the attributes. Are you using .prop or ,attr or .set. Play around with .attr el.attr({ title: { text: card.title }}) and for custom object .set   el.set({ city: new City('NYC) })

Comment: I found a way to do it with

cell.attributes.attr = foundCell;
graph.resetCells(res.res.graph.cells);